# DDD - Is Aggregate root as factory ok?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

Is it ok for my aggregate root to act as a factory for entities that he manages?

E.G: is it ok for my aggregate root "Question" to instantiate a entity "Answer"?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it ok for my aggregate root to act as a factory for entities that he manages?

Almost.

The aggregate root isn't an entity as such, but a role played by an entity.  Think interface - it gives the application a restricted access to the domain model, encapsulating the actual implementation.

It's natural to have the aggregate be responsible for its own state; after all, all of the components of the aggregate are going to be drawn from the same data model (they are persisted together).

Within your entity (which is acting as the aggregate root), you want your code to align as closely as possible with the language of the domain.  That will usually mean that you don't have a "factory", as in the design pattern, but instead have some entity in the model that produces the managed entities.

Udi Dahan touched on this, somewhat obliquely, when he wrote [Don't Create Aggregate Roots](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/).

> Customers don’t just appear out of thin air.

The entities in your model all come from other entities in your model.  Turtles all the way down.

So introducing the factory design pattern into the domain language is a bit sketch.

Because the domain model lives in memory... because its unusual for the domain model to have side effects... a lot of the usual motivations for abstracting connection points don't apply.  If you find yourself, for example, wanting to inject a mock into your domain model for unit testing, then something has gone badly wrong (into domain services, yes, but not into entities).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is, if the code is a simple `new Answer (someArguments, ...)`.

If it is a more complicated process then you should extract this code into a `AnswerFactory` class.

EDIT:
The desire to create a clean code dictates this and not DDD. A rule from DDD that is relevant to your question is that Domain (so all classes from the Domain layer) should not depend on any other layers (like Infrastructure or Application).

Comment: The factories should be in the infrastructure... does that mean that i should reference that project or should the factory be injected by the repository (when retrieving objects) and/or other factories (when creating new roots)?

Comment: @Leonardo Then you'd have a dependency from Domain to Infrastructure, which is bad

Comment: @Leonardo You don't inject anything inside the aggregates, ever. The `AnswerFactory` class that I've suggested is from the Domain layer and it is created by the `Question` aggregate using the `new` operator. If the `Answer` entity needs information from the outside then that information is passed by the client code using the method on the `Question` aggregate that creates the `Answer` entity and not injected into the factory class.